# String to date milliseconds with javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var decodeEntities = (function() {
      // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
      var element = document.createElement('div');

      function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
        if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
          // strip script/html tags
          str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
          str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
          element.innerHTML = str;
          str = element.textContent;
          element.textContent = '';
        }

        return str;
      }

      return decodeHTMLEntities;
    })();   
var points_data = JSON.parse(decodeEntities("<%= (data) %>"));


  var points = [];

  for(var i in points_data){
    var p = {"type":"line","showInLegend":"true"};
    p.name = i;
    //alert(p.name);
    p.dataPoints = [];
    for(var j=0; j<points_data[i].length; j++)
    {
        //alert(new Date(points_data[i][j].dateTime));
        //alert(getTime());
        //alert(points_data[i][j].value);
        var str = points_data[i][j].dateTime;
        alert(str);
        var sim = moment(str,"yyyy-M-D H:M:S").format('x');
        alert(sim);
        p.dataPoints.push({x: sim, y: parseFloat(points_data[i][j].value)});
    }
    points.push(p);

  }
</script>
```

> Its give me invalid date error. How can i covert this string to
>   milliseconds like "1467172803000"
>
> And my Json Have data like this:

```
{"systimesec":[{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:28:58","value":"58.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:00","value":"0.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:02","value":"2.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:04","value":"4.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:06","value":"6.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:08","value":"8.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:10","value":"10.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:12","value":"12.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:14","value":"14.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:16","value":"16.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:18","value":"18.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:20","value":"20.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:22","value":"22.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:24","value":"24.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:26","value":"26.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:28","value":"28.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:30","value":"30.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:32","value":"32.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:34","value":"34.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:36","value":"36.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:38","value":"38.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:40","value":"40.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:42","value":"42.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:44","value":"44.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:46","value":"46.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:48","value":"48.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:50","value":"50.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:52","value":"52.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:54","value":"54.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:56","value":"56.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:58","value":"58.0"}],"sysperfcputotal":[{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:28:59","value":"20.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:01","value":"12.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:03","value":"7.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:05","value":"9.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:07","value":"12.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:09","value":"15.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:11","value":"18.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:13","value":"9.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:15","value":"5.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:17","value":"12.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:19","value":"34.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:21","value":"22.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:23","value":"15.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:25","value":"15.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:27","value":"8.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:29","value":"15.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:31","value":"6.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:33","value":"14.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:35","value":"17.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:37","value":"8.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:39","value":"4.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:41","value":"5.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:43","value":"3.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:45","value":"5.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:47","value":"5.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:49","value":"2.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:51","value":"9.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:53","value":"6.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:55","value":"28.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:57","value":"18.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:59","value":"25.0"}],"sysperfdisktime":[{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:28:59","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:01","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:03","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:05","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:07","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:09","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:11","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:13","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:15","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:17","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:19","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:21","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:23","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:25","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:27","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:29","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:31","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:33","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:35","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:37","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:39","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:41","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:43","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:45","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:47","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:49","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:51","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:53","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:55","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:57","value":"100.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-06-29 01:29:59","value":"100.0"}]}
```

> Now i am using moment instead of date its shows still "Inavlid date"

Answer (score 3):

Look at JS doc for [Date()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). You can use `getTime()` method.

```js
var str = "2016-06-29 01:07:18";
var sim = new Date(str).getTime();
alert(sim);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.parse`

```
var miliSeconds =  Date.parse(sim)
```

This will return number of milliseconds between `January 1, 1970` and your date `2016-06-29 01:07:18`

**Output**

`1467144438000`

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.js.

```
<script>
var str = "2016-06-29 01:07:18";
var sim = moment(str,"yyyy-M-D H:M:S").format('x');
alert(sim);
</script>
```

Comment: its giving me invalid date i edit the question please check

Comment: impossible. the code above runs with momemt.js library loaded